# prove the product of finitely many compact spaces need be compact using nets

Tags: general-topology

So I need to prove the product of two compact spaces need be compact using nets. I know that a net is a generalization of a sequence where the indexing set is an arbitrary directed set, but I do not see how to apply nets to this proof. I also know a space is compact iff every net has a convergent subnet. But do not see how to apply this fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Do two compact spaces and then use induction.   Obviously if you have a net in the product,  by projection you get a net in each factor.  So say your net is $z_•=(x_•,y_•)$. Take a convergent subnet $s_•=x\circ f$ (of $x_•$).  Then take a convergent subnet $t_•=y\circ f\circ g$ of $y\circ f$.
Then $z\circ f\circ g$ is your convergent subnet (of $z_•$).  It'll converge because it converges in each factor.

Comment: So I let $(x_\lambda)_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ and $(y_\delta)_{\delta \in \Delta}$ be two nets in two compact spaces $X,Y$ then they each have a convergent subnet whose cross product is in $X \times Y$?

Comment: Well, you start with a net $z_•$ in $X×Y$.  Then use the projections to get $x_•,y_•$.

Comment: So use projections onto $X,Y$ respectively to get $x_\cdot$ and $y_\cdot$?

Comment: I didn't describe it quite right.   See my edit for the correction.